Javascript validate each single character onChange or onKeyPress
I have an input field. I need the input to have the following format:
AC-123456789

First character can either be A or B in uppercase
Second character can be any uppercase letter or number
There has to be a hyphen after the second character
After the hyphen there can be any number of characters between 1 and 9

I would like for the check to happen onKeyPress (in React). So if the first character is not right it will return an alerto of some kind. If the second character is not correct then I get another error. So on.
Right now my regex looks like this:
/^[A,B][A-Z0-9]-\d{1,9}$/.test(value)
But this only checks once the whole input is the correct format and not after each single character is inputed in the field.

You'll need to create a validation for each substring case because events are asynchronous. — e.g. a validation case for each of the following string lengths: 0, 1, 2, 3, ≥ 4 — or if you don't care to give such specific validation help to the user in each scenario, you can modify your regex to use alternation patterns (|).

my first naive thought is to use /^[A,B](|[A-Z0-9](|-(|\d{1,9})))$/.test(value) to check the validity of the partial input - should After the hyphen there can be any number of characters be After the hyphen there can be 1 to 9 digits?

@JaromandaX After the hyphen there can be 1 to 9 digits. Your solution works perfectly!

The answer below is better I think - as I said, mine was a naive first thought :p

Maybe also ^[AB](?:[A-Z\d](?:-\d{0,9})?)?$ (note that I removed the comma from [A,B] which looked like not to be intended).

For this specific regex, you could add a "mask", ie: your string + the end of a string you know is valid and then check if your regex passes:


const isValidString = (input) => {
  if(!input.length) return false;
  const validStr = "AC-123456789";
  const maskedStr = input + validStr.slice(input.length);
  return /^[A,B][A-Z0-9]-\d{1,9}$/.test(maskedStr);
}

console.log(isValidString("AX-12")); // true
console.log(isValidString("AX-12Z")); // false
console.log(isValidString("AX-123456789")); // true
console.log(isValidString("AX-1234567891")); // false



